# The Thumbnail aspect Ratio Issue

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have used thumbnail like this in my wordpress theme's one template →

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
```

In the browser it is rendering like this →

```
<img 
    width="300" 
    height="220" 
    src="http://example.com/image-300x220.jpg" 
    class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" 
    alt="" 
    srcset="
        http://example.com/image-300x220.jpg 300w, 
        http://example.com/image.jpg 640w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"
>
```

My first question is how to put height = auto is there any function that can help us to achieve this?
such as `responsive-img`

In short, I am asking should I control the width through the CSS or WordPress gives some function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the height value from your img URL, you can use this function:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_height', 10, 5 );
function remove_thumbnail_height( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/height=\"\d*\"/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

This will replace the height with an empty value. Note that you can't use `Auto` as a value for the `height` property. It won't be validated by w3 validator. However, you can set the height to auto in your CSS:

```
.wp-post-image {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: @TheWPNovice You're welcome. You can always try the answer and accept it ONLY if it solved your problem.

Comment: My atom(editor) is hanged I need to restart the machine(desktop). I will get back to you ASAP. thanks for your help sir. Thanks for editing the question correctly. You are a very knowledgeable person.

Comment: @TheWPNovice You are welcome. Just sharing what i know, which isn't much. take your time.

Comment: @TheWPNovice You are welcome, as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this,

you can use second parameter as an array of attributes as

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium', ['class' => 'img-responsive', 'alt' => get_the_title()]);
```

If you are not using bootstrap framework, in style sheet put

```
.img-responsive{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please note, this will drop the `srcset`, which will remove the responsiveness from the image.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I changed the code it should work fine what do you say.